# Visual Studio and add-in unloading

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, vsx, extensibility

When I remove an add-in from Visual Studio's add-in menu, it doesn't get unloaded from memory. Does anyone know if I can write some code for my add-in (in C#) that would force this unloading. Is this even possible, or do I have to restart VS?

Answer (score 5):

If your DLL is written in managed code there is no way to force it to be unloaded as a Visual Studio Add-In.  The CLR does not support such a mechanism.

The only way to force a DLL to be unloaded from a process is to tear down all AppDomains which have loaded the DLL.  In a Visual Studio Add-In scenario, the add-in will be loaded into the default AppDomain.  Tearing this down necessitates tearing down the entire process :(

Comment: Is there anyway to load the Add-in in a seperate AppDomain?

Comment: @Mark this is not supported. Both the Add-In and VSIX APIs are designed for running within the same AppDomain.