# How to make a visual studio add-in that cannot be unloaded?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, add-in

I'm writing a Visual Studio add-in using C/C++. I am not familiar with the COM architecture. In fact I'm learning Windows programming.

I can see an OnDisconnect() call back into my add-in. I tried returning S_FALSE, but that does not seem to stop the add-in from being unloaded.

So my questions is, is it possible to make an add-in that cannot be unloaded (either through the Tools menu or programatically), and if yes, will some magic return value from OnDisconnect() do the job, or some other trick is required?

I also saw another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346674/visual-studio-and-add-in-unloading) that asks exactly the opposite. From the answer, it seems that the DLL still resides in the memory when an add-in is unloaded. So maybe there is a way to reload the add-in as soon as it is unloaded?

Comment: Do you mean "How to irritate a programmer whose VS is crashing?"  Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Well, it's a requirement from my client. So....

Comment: Why does this sound like some kind of malware? Something that can never be unloaded... No offense intended though.

Comment: Good luck with that one, the behavior is probably blocked by ms so that they can use the /safemode switch. Whats the name of the client so that I can be sure to never use thier products? (just kidding, dont give the name).

Comment: @lc, it does sound like a malware, I agree :-) The same techniques can be used to achieve different things. Just like anti-virus software sometimes borrows techniques from viruses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this.  If you really need functionalty that cannot be unloaded while VS is running, you should write a package instead of an add-in.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I haven't used Visual Studio SDK before but I'll look into this option...